# Are list parameters supported in OpenRasta? how they should be sent?

Tags: rest, openrasta, restful-url

If I have a resource handler method receiving an object list as parameter (int list, string list or any object type list), i.e.:

```
 public class TasksCollecionHandler 
    { 
        public TaskCollection GetTasksByEngineer(List<int> engineerIds) 
        { 
            .... 
        } 
        public TaskCollecion GetTasksByEngineer(List<Engineer> engineers) 
        { 
           .... 
        } 
    }
```

1. Is OpenRasta supporting this kind of arguments?
2. How the HTTP request including values for kind of arguments should look like?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the codec. Using json or xml data contracts it'd be whatever format the datacontract mapping follows.

If you use forms and html, the format would be

```
engineers:0.FirstName=john&engineers:0.LastName=doe&engineers:1.FirstName=other
```

Comment: If we take the sample of List<int> can it be put in a singe GET request string?

Comment: I haven't written any code to cover that scenario, so not out of the box no. You can always provide your own binder on the attribute to parse the string yourself i'd think.